# Best way to handle graphing and display of large data sets

Tags: javascript, php, sql, symfony

Our website provides various data services to our clients; one of which is gauge data. Some gauges log information every 15 minutes, some every minute. This data is sent to our SQL database.

All of this data is displayed via a graph (generated server side via PHP and JPGraphs) with each individual log entry being displayed as a row in a collapsible table (jquery 1.10.2).

When a client wants to view the data, they select a date range and which gauges they would like to view.  If they want to view the last 3 days of a gauge that logs every minute then it loads pretty quickly. If they want to view 2 of those then it takes around 15-30 seconds to load. The real problem comes when they want to view a months worth of data; especially more than 1 gauge.  This can take upwards of 15-20 minutes to load and the browser repeatedly asks if we want to stop the script from populating the collapsible table rows(jquery).

Obviously this is a problem since clients want a relatively fast response (1-5 min max). Ideally, we would also like to be able to pull gauge data from several months at a time. The only way we can do that now is to pull data 2 weeks at a time and compile the total manually.

For reference: If I wanted to pull a months data for 2 of our once-a-minute-logging gauges, then there would be 86,400 rows added via jQuery to a collapsible table. The page takes approx. 5 minutes to load and the browser is terribly slow during this time period.

My question is: What is the best way to pull/graph/populate data using a PHP based server (Symfony 1.4 framework) and javascript?

Should we look into upgrading our allotted processing power/RAM(we are hosted by GoDaddy)?  Is there a faster way to populate collapsibles than with jquery? All of our calculatoins are done server side. Should we just pull the raw data and let the client side do the data processing? Should we split the data processing between client and server?

Here's a screen shot of the web page. Its cropped so that more client-sensitive information is not displayed:

[image]

Comment: This might not work for you very well because of the fact that you need to graphs to be displayed as well. However, one thing I have done before whenever I have had to pull very large data-sets (millions of rows) is to not actually pass the entire thing to the client. Pass only the first 200. Then give an ability for the user to make a request for more data. Something like infinity scroll for example. If you are interested I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: If there is processing that needs to be done on the server, you could pre-process and cache the data. Join together pre-cached data (array_merge maybe) is easy and probably a lot faster. Other than that, you could load the data in chunks. Paginate the data and/or load in via ajax when they scroll down.

Comment: 84'000 data points is nearly unmanageable for someone reading data no? have you considered aggregating the data prior to graphing to make the data set being graphed a bit smaller?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @Pompey I am interested in a more detailed answer. I need all of the data at once server-side so I can create a graph, so are you suggesting I cache this data and only send a fraction for the collapsible table? Then I would send more data for the collapsible via ajax if they scroll down far enough?  Also here's a couple screen shots of my web page. Its cropped so more detailed client information is excluded: http://imgur.com/a/wRF1d#0

Comment: @twelfth The clients don't want any "fluffed" data. In other words they don't want any sort of estimations or rounding in regards to the data being graphed. They want an as-accurate-as-possible graph and data display (i.e. no rounding an hours worth of readings into 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to my comment.

Since you need the entire data-set only on the server side (you create your graph on the server), this means that you don't actually need to send the entire data-set to the client.

Instead send a small portion to the client. Let's say the first 200 results. Then you can go ahead and cache the rest of the result-set into a JSON file (lite database, whatever you want really). Then create an interface where the user can request for more data. Infinity scroll is nice but has its own problems. Maybe just a button that says load more data. As people have said anything more than a few hundred data points in a table at one time is crazy to have because people won't look at it anyways. Then when they hit the button to get more data, you send an AJAX request to the server with the correct parameters for what data you want.

For example the first time they click getMoreData() you want to get the next 200 data points. So you send getMoreData(start=200, length=200). Your server picks up the AJAX request and finds the correct data in the JSON file or the lite database, wherever you have cached the results. And the user can keep requesting more data (making sure you update your start parameter), and you only ever return a small subset. The user doesn't even realize that they don't have the whole data-set there in front of them because it looks like they do.

One that is complicated about this is sorting and searching. If you want to implement those then you need to make sure you go to the server side and sort/search through the cached results.

So basically you have a system where you can create the entire graph on the server side which shouldn't take long. What does take long is the loading of the entire data-set to the client side. So you break up that up into small chunks. You can even easily create pagination and the such with this method.