# how to render json in frontend whose size if more than 2gb

Tags: javascript, json, web-services, frontend, browser-cache

GET call /giveMyTree is giving a Json, more than 2 gb in size.In frontend side we are parsing that json and processing on entire json and displaying the data json contains.

Json structure is in nested structure.

{

tree[1]

|_ O{0}

```
|_ branch[50]
     |__
     |    Point[1000]
     |      |___ branch {225}
     |             :
     |             :
     |___ Line[10000]
     :       |____start{1}
     :       |           |
     :       |            __ branch{122}
     .       |                 :
     .       |                 : 
             |____end{1} 
                        | .....

     .                         :
     .                         :
```

}

we display 1000 node, 10000 link and other data after parsing whole json.

I am unable to display this data on browser, browser is either crashing or  hangs while processing this data.Is there any way where I can load this data to browser and display the graph to end user.

Comment: This much large amount of data on the client side is very bad. Some sort of pagination or an ability to fetch more data on user request should be included on the page. Check a [similar SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19596403/best-way-to-handle-graphing-and-display-of-large-data-sets).

Answer (score 0):

With the API you designed, there isn't. The browser will have to load the JSON to parse it, and 2 GB of JSON will create more than 2 GB of JS objects in memory, give or take.

Even a 4K display can at most show up to 32 MB of data at once (4K*2K*4 = 32M), and if you have mostly text, far less than that, so you don't need 1 GB of data in a single transmission.

Current browsers have problems parsing some hundred megabytes of JSON, so you will have to change your API in such a way that there are smaller chunks transmitted at a time - you should get every JSON answer down to less than 20 MB in size, either by removing details from the general tree (and fetching them when the user opens a single entry), or by breaking the full tree into smaller chunks (only load the root node and all subnodes, and when a subnode is expanded, fetch the sub-subnodes).

Comment: Thanks Alexander. Approach you suggest  "only load the root node and all subnodes, and when a subnode is expanded, fetch the sub-subnodes"

Comment: Can we implement this approach in fronted side. Like we load entire json in  browser and store in JSON object [here I assumes browser uses host machine ram so json object storage capacity is depends on host machine memory limit ] when user click on any node we parse only that node  and display in UI.

Comment: You can try, but I expect on 90% of the machines the browser will crash.

Comment: I have enough memory that browser can use and enough CPU capacity.What can be reason for browser crash ?